# Can't download .cs file

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I was wondering if someone can tell me why I can't make a link so a person can download a custom .cs file?

```
<a href="~/File/Tools.cs" download="" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

This is how I create the file (part of the code):

```
string pathString = Server.MapPath("~/File/");
string fileName = "Tools.cs";
pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);
...
System.IO.File.Create(pathString).Dispose();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(pathString);
tw.WriteLine("using System;");
tw.WriteLine("using System.Collections.Generic;");
tw.WriteLine("using System.Linq;");
tw.WriteLine("using System.Web;");
...
```

If I look in the folder the file is there and it works. But I just can't download it.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because iis doesn't allow you to download .cs file.
for example change its extension to .zip and download it again.
of course you can allow it but is security risk.and it is not recommended
[image: Allow iis to download .cs files]

Answer (score 1):

Use this to download the file when clicking on the link (instead of navigating to the file):

```
<a href="~/File/Tools.cs" download>Download</a>
```

The `download` attribute specifies that the target will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink. This attribute is only used if the `href` attribute is set.

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download)